# ¿como cambio dolphin por nemo como gestor de archivos predeterminado en mxlinux21 Kde?

Tags: linux, debian

Amigos he tenido problemas con dolphin a la hora de gestionar carpetas que esta syncronizada con Google Drive: se pega feo, se traba y deja de funcionar.

Nemo funciona muy bien no se paga ni nada. ¿Como lo hago mi gestor de archivos predeterminado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para hacer de nemo mi gestor de archivos predeterminado debes buscar "Aplicaciones predeterminadas" aparecera una ventana, donde dice gestor de archivos cambia dolphin por Archivos, si no aparece selecciona opcion otros: aparecera una ventana emergente.

debajo de seleccionar un gestor de archivos favorito coloca `nemo` y dale aceptar y luego en la parte inferior aplicar

Lo siguiente es abrir la terminal para activar el demonio de nemo al iniciar el sistema y desactivar dolphin:

```
xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
```

luego:

```
cd /usr/share/dbus-1/services/
cp org.kde.dolphin.FileManager1.service org.kde.dolphin.FileManager1.service.back
sudo nano org.kde.dolphin.FileManager1.service
```

edita el archivo org.kde.dolphin.FileManager1.service para que quede de la siquiente manera:

```
Name=org.freedesktop.FileManager1
Exec=/usr/bin/nemo --no-default-window
```

guardalo y reinicia el pc y listo: nemo es tu gestor de archivos predeterminado en Mxlinux21 Kde.

si ves que nemo arranca lento, puedes colocarlo que inicie automaticamente cuando abras sesion:

1)busca en el menu de aplicaciones "Pantalla de inicio de sesión (SDDM)"
2) te abrira una ventana busca la opcion Autoarranque
3) en la parte inferior seleciona añadir y despues anadir aplicacion
4) en la ventana que aparece debajo de elegir una aplicacion pega esto:

```
/usr/bin/nemo --no-default-window %U
```

le das aceptar y listo nemo se iniciara en el background y abrira mas rapido.

Tambien puedes probar ejecutando nemo con la prioridad mas alta como lo dice aqui: https://forum.mxlinux.org/viewtopic.php?p=697811#p697811

si quieres revertir los cambios en terminal:

```
cd /usr/share/dbus-1/services/
sudo rm -rf org.kde.dolphin.FileManager1.service
sudo mv org.kde.dolphin.FileManager1.service.back org.kde.dolphin.FileManager1.service
```

Ahora en Aplicaciones predeterminadas elige dolphin de nuevo como tu gestor de archivos y quita del inicio a nemo.

nota: si nemo aparece en ingles, ponlo en español de esta forma: https://facilitarelsoftwarelibre.blogspot.com/2021/01/antix-mxlinux-en-espanol.html

```
sudo apt-get install cinnamon-l10n
```

Para instalar nemo basta con:

```
sudo apt-get install nemo nemo-fileroller
```

Comment: No entiendo porqué el -1, me parece bien que propongas cosas que podrían interesarle a otros usuarios y que resolviste por tu cuenta. Si acaso, creo que te faltó agregar cómo instalar Nemo, por lo demás, lo veo bien. +1

Comment: Si, pues talvez por alguna regla de ortografia o lo que sea: son exigentes. Pero cuando puedo siempre me gusta compartir mis soluciones porque muchas veces he estado barado y esta web o alguna otra me a ayudado a desehuesarme jjj.